# How do I match a number not followed by a letter except for a certain substring

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a number not followed by a letter except if followed by the substring `See`
I am not even sure if this is possible but I've tried the following which did not work.

https://regex101.com/r/agExmP/1

[image]

My question is:
How do I match a number (number 7 in the example above) which is not followed by a letter except when followed by the substring `See`
There should also be a match if not a letter. e.g. dot, comma, dash

Comment: Like `\b(\d+) See\b`  https://regex101.com/r/Vmkjp9/1 ?

Comment: Or, `\d+(?=\s*See)` / `\b\d+(?=\s*See\b)`? I think you should add test cases to clarify your requirements. Why did you make the positive lookahead optional?

Comment: Try `\b(?<!\d\.)\d+(?!\.\d)(?=\s*(?:See\b|[^\w\s]|_))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 separate lookahead assertions are from the current position.

You can assert `See` to the right, but using `(?![A-Za-z])` will prevent to match it as it starts with `S`. If you remove that part, you still have an optional lookahead, which will cause more digits to match.

If you make the lookahead not optional, you will match a digit followed by a space, but you only want the digit so you can add the space to the lookahead.

You could update the pattern to:

```
\b\d+(?= See\b)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsZdxN/1).

To prevent partial matches, you can surround the pattern with word boundaries `\b`

Or you can capture 1 (or more) digits in a group followed by matching `See` without using any lookarounds.

```
\b(\d+) See\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KvxPzt/1)

**Edit**

If you also want to allow matching a digit followed by a dot, comma or dash, there should be optional spaces before `See` to allow another character directly after the digit.

To prevent partial matches for the digit, you can assert a whitespace boundary to the left, and allow either See or any of the allowed characters using a character class to the right.

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?!\.\d)(?=\s*(?:See\b|[.,-]))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/grujD2/1)

Comment: All suggestions work but there should be a match if not followed by a letter e.g. ad dot or a dash

Comment: @MK01111000 The digit only matches when there is `See` to the right which automatically excludes a dot or dash. Can you give an example string where the digits should be matched?

Comment: @MK01111000 I have added an update to the answer.